# Hibernate many to many bidirectional - two way @JsonManagedReference & @JsonBackReference

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

To avoid infinite recursions I am using @JsonManagedReference & @JsonBackReference . But while retrieving results I only get expected results one way.

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="THIRD_TABLE", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID")})
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();

-----------
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="teachers")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Student> winners = new HashSet<>();
```

getting Teachers per student woks well , but getting Students per teacher does not work. JsonBackReference prevents this.

Is it possible to have both the annotations on one field and get it working two ways.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to avoid recursion, you can use **@JsonIdentityInfo**. It will generate id for each object, and replace a repeated object by its id if it is repeated.

Here is a simple parent/child example:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=IntSequenceGenerator.class)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class Parent {
  private List<Child> children=new ArrayList<>();
  private String name="parent";

  public Parent() {
    super();
    children.add(new Child(this,"foo"));
    children.add(new Child(this,"bar"));
  }

  public List<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

}
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class Child {
  private Parent parent;
  private String pseudo="toto";
  public Child(Parent parent, String pseudo) {
    super();
    this.parent = parent;
    this.pseudo = pseudo;
  }

}



public class SOJson {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Parent object=new Parent();
    String json1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString( object);
    System.out.println("write parent: "+json1);
    String json2 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object.getChildren().get(0));
    System.out.println("write child: "+json2);

  }
}
```

The result:

```
write parent: {"@id":1,"children":[{"parent":1,"pseudo":"foo"},{"parent":1,"pseudo":"bar"}],"name":"parent"}
write child: {"parent":{"@id":1,"children":[{"parent":1,"pseudo":"foo"},{"parent":1,"pseudo":"bar"}],"name":"parent"},"pseudo":"foo"}
```

You see that there is a recursion between the child and the parent, and if you remove the @JsonIdentityInfo you will have a stackoverflow.

Of course you will need to stop your recursion somewhere or else you will dump all your database! Use either @jsonIgnore to stop your recursion somewhere, or Hibernate4Module to stop recursion on unloaded lazy properties. (I prefer to use both)